# Plain Old Ruby Method not updating time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method

```
def call
  user.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  user.save!
  user.regenerate_password_reset_token
  UserMailer.password_reset(user).deliver_later(queue: "low")
end

def user
  @user = User.find_by_email(@params)
end
```

and I'm trying to reset the password_reset_token and the password_reset_sent_at

```
User::PasswordReset.new("foo@foobar.com").call
```

I see the token updated but it does not update the `password_reset_sent_at`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every occurrence of `user` within `call` is another invocation of the `user` method, creating another `User` object from the record in the database and storing it in `@user`. The effect is similar to if you had written

```
def call
   User.find_by_email(@params).password_sent_at = Time.zone.now
   User.find_by_email(@params).save!
   ... etc ...
end
```

The changes you make to the *first* copy of the User record you retrieve, are never saved before you go and get a new copy.

I think the idiom you are aiming for involves defining `user` like this:

```
def user
  @user ||= User.find_by_email(@params)
end
```

Defined that way, `User.find_by_email` will only be called once, and the result stored in `@user`. Subsequent calls to `user` will re-use the existing value of `@user`, a technique called [memoization](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/).